# Сборка gulp. Как сделать другую точку входа, не index.html

Tags: html, gulp

изучаю gulp и использую эту сборку https://github.com/maxdenaro/youtube-creatix-marathon и хотелось бы узнать, как изменить точку входа. Допустим, вместо файла index.html был бы main.html. Заранее благодарю за ответы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное речь идёт не о самом **Gulp**, а о модуле [**Browsersync**](https://browsersync.io/), если так, то за смену "стартовой" директории или файла отвечает параметр `startPath` - [документация](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-startPath).

Получается в вашем случае достаточно указать:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
 browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './',
      startPath: './main.html'
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

у меня startPath не сработало, зато сработало index: "main.html"